# Working with cash in Java

Tags: java, android, bigdecimal

EDIT2: I'm an idiot >.<

EDIT: I need to cut this problem down to size.
I will post a simpler problem later this evening.

This whole time, all I needed to ask was, "Can someone remind me how to work with cash in Java?", but no... I always find the most complex ways of saying the simplest of things x_x

EDIT3: Just for clarity, I've also just found this: http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2003/07/MoneyInJava.html
which helps with using BigDecimal.

Comment: I advise breaking this down into separate, short, and concise questions, because as it is, it's difficult to help. The question regarding the use of `BigDecimal`, or specifically what exact problem you have, is unclear; you'd be best to show a small section of code that demonstrates the exact problem. Then, the problem regarding layout should be in a separate question. Also, I happened to notice `bdMilageRate = new BigDecimal(0.90d)` which may be a typo.

Comment: @Trevor : I thought you could do that with decimals - Adding d to the end of Doubles.... f to the end of Floats...
Maybe that doesn't matter?
Thanks for your constructive criticism, though. I'll develop a smaller application to find the problem - and will come back to StackOverflow if I need to.

Comment: Ah - what I was wondering about was the `0.90`. I wondered if you meant to initialise it with `0.00`. (I haven't inspected much else within your code yet; it just caught my eye.)

Comment: Yeah, bdMilageRate refers to the amount this Shop pays it's Drivers for each Delivery they do.
Milage is £0.90 per Delivery.

Comment: Ah - just realised. OK.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I've seen to deal with currency values is to internally handle them as a non-decimal type and only perform the conversion on output and input as needed.

Eg: $10.34 could / should be stored as an Integer or Long 1034 and then displayed as (Integer) 1034/100, 1034 mod 100 as needed (note: my java modulus operator may / probably is off - don't use it often enough).

Any time that you're dealing with floating point numbers there is a risk of loss of precision.  Since currency is defined to have a fixed floating point and a fixed number of decimals scaling all the values by 100 removes this concern.  This does cut back on the maximum amount of currency that can be represented but generally this is less of a concern than accuracy.

Comment: I had to kick myself. Of course! It's basic mathematics >.<
I'm gonna blame that on being out of practise :P
Thanks for your help! I'll be fine now XD